# EF Core 2.2.6: Unable to map 2 foreign keys to the same table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am having issues trying to map two fields that are foreign keys into the same table.  The use case is for a modifier and creator.  My class already has the Ids, and then I wanted to add the full User object as virtual.

I am using a base class so that each of my tables have the same audit fields:

```
public class Entity
{
        public long? ModifiedById { get; set; }
        public long CreatedById { get; set; } = 1;

        [ForeignKey("CreatedById")] 
        public virtual User CreatedByUser { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ModifiedById")]
        public virtual User ModifiedByUser { get; set; }
}
```

The child class is very simple:

```
public class CircleUserSubscription : Entity
{
        [Required]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public long SponsorUserId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("SponsorUserId")]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        public long TestId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("TestId")]
        public virtual User Test { get; set; }
}
```

This is a standard junction table.

When I try to generate the migration, I am getting errors that I don't understand fully.

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'CircleUserSubscription.User' of type 'User'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

I tried what this answer had, but the code is basically the same: https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/54418186/ef-core-2-2---two-foreign-keys-to-same-table

An inverse property doesn't make sense since every table will have a reference to the user table.

For reference, here is the User entity:

```
public class User : Entity
{
        public long Id { get; set; } 
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I am hoping you all can help me out, TIA :)

EDIT: One thing to note, all of this worked fine when the entity class was as follows:

```
public class Entity
{
    public long? ModifiedById { get; set; }
    public long CreatedById { get; set; } = 1;
}
```

It was only after I added the entity that things went awry.

Comment: Isn't `public virtual Test User` actually `public virtual User Test`?

Comment: Also I'm not getting any exception when creating migration (although I'm wondering how are you going to create the very first `User` with required `CreatedById`, but that's another story).

Comment: It was a bad copy and paste for your first comment.  
We use has data for your second question

Comment: Ok. But it doesn't reproduce on my side - clean project with just classes from question + simple derived `DbContext` containing `User` and `CircleUserSubscription` db sets - no fluent configuration. EF Core 2.2.6, SqlServer. So there must be something in your real case which is causing the issue. W/o repro there is nothing we can do though.

Comment: @IvanStoev I added more information in the question.  Everything worked fine when the Entity class was only the long Id for the two fields.  It was only once I added the User object for those two Ids that things fell apart.  Does that seem to be relevant information?

Comment: The "problem" is that it is working for me as is. There must be something not included in the post - for instance fluent configuration having `WithOne()` or `HasOne()`.